# change most significant bit of an 8 bit binary to 0 and get the decimal value of first seven bits only

Tags: java

I have a binary number and i want to get the decimal value of only the seven bits and not include the 8th bit. How do i go about this in java.

eg. 130 as binary => 10000010, I only need 00000010 =>2 ,ie, change only the most significant bit to 0.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [bit-mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask):

```
int y = x & 0x7F;
```

Comment: @Pranay: some more detail for this great answer: you'll "mask" `1000 0010` using `0111 1111` Think of this mask as you marking a `1` for every bit you want to "keep its state" (For example, if the original bit is `0`, `0&1=0`, and if its `1`, `1&1=1` So anding by `1` gives you the original value of the bit) and a `0` for a bit you want to "mask" to `0`.

Answer (score 5):

```
  byte b =10;
  byte result  = (byte) (b & 127);
```

Under the cover it would be

```
    00001010 //10 in dec   
AND 01111111 // our mask ,127 in dec
  = 00001010 //10
```

another example

```
    10000001 //129 in dec   
AND 01111111 // our mask ,127 in dec
  = 00000001 //1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean getBit(int b, int p) {
    int mask = 1 << 8 - p;
    return (b & mask) > 0;
}

private static int setBit(int b, int p) {
    int mask = 1 << 8 - p;
    return b | mask;
}

private static int unsetBit(int b, int p) {
    int mask = 1 << 8 - p;
    return b & ~mask;
}
```